# Regex not working properly

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$text='<td valign="top">text</td><td>more text</td>';
preg_match('/<td valign="?top"?>.*<\/td>)/s', $text, $matches);

?>
```

`$matches[0]` should return`<td valign="top">text</td>` but it returns `<td valign="top">text</td><td>more text</td>`.  Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex for bbcode seems to fail on long sentences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004336/regex-for-bbcode-seems-to-fail-on-long-sentences), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004336/regex-for-bbcode-seems-to-fail-on-long-sentences/7004356#7004356 for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `.*` pattern un-greedy by adding a `?`:

```
preg_match('/<td valign="?top"?>.*?<\/td>)/s', $text, $matches);
                                ^^^
```

Here is an example of greedy vs. non-greedy regex: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html

> Why?

That is how regex work. You might be looking for an XML Parser instead:

```
$text='<td valign="top">text</td><td>more text</td>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string("<x>$text</x>");
list($td) = $xml->xpath('td[@valign="top"]');
echo $td->asXML(); # <td valign="top">text</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

? cannot stand alone. It's a modifier and greedy operator. It means looking for the closest match. Maybe you need a .+? in you expression.

Answer (score 0):

try this `<td valign.+?\/td>` I think it works